# Expose constants to all sub-modules in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, module

I have a Rails nested module as follow:

```
lib
 - Parent
   - Child1.rb
   - Child2.rb
```

In Child1.rb I define:

```
module Parent
  module Child1
  end
end
```

Child2 module is defined similarly.

In my model, I call:

```
model MyModel
   include Parent::Child1
   include Parent::Child2
end
```

I have a few constants to be shared between Child1 and Child2. How should I go about implementing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a file called parent.rb in lib to define the parent module and put the constants in there

```
module Parent
  CONSTANT1 = "1"
  CONSTANT2 = "2"
end
```

both constants will now be available in your child modules

Structure will look like

```
lib
 - Parent
   - child1.rb
   - child2.rb
 - parent.rb
```